# Calling Jquery function in DART lang

Tags: javascript, jquery, dart, dart-editor

I'm trying to convert the following jquery script in DART :

```
<script>
    (function($){
        $(window).load(function(){
            $(".content").mCustomScrollbar();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

I've wrote the following code in DART :

```
  js.context
  .callMethod(r'$', ['.content"'])
  .callMethod('mCustomScrollbar');
```

But it's not working.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add some description of your error.  "it's not working" tells us nothing, and it's difficult to answer this as-is.

Comment: In fact , I don't have a specific error. I'm trying to use the jquery custom scroller. http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ , and it seems to do not call the mcustomscrollbar function. So I think that my dart code is poorly written

Comment: Is the wrong quote a copy/past error? .callMethod(r'$', ['.content*"*'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside the typo in `['.content"']` (instead of `['.content']`) it looks good to me if you are using `import dart:js;` and not `import 'package:js/js.dart'`.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong quote is just a copy/past error. The code in DART is correct when using import dart.js

In fact , to use the jQuery custom content scroller plugin http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ ,  I have to include the following script :

```
<!-- Google CDN jQuery with fallback to local -->
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/minified/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

I forgot to do it. so everything is Ok right now. 
Thank You guys!